# bind_param() error - call to method function on bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

I am very new to php and this is my first attempt at using mysqli. I can't seem to figure out why I am getting this error? I have reviewed similar questions on it but I still don't understand what the problem is.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once('abstractDAO.php');

class customerDAO extends abstractDAO {

function __construct() {
    try{
        parent::__construct();
    } catch(mysqli_sql_exception $e){
        throw $e;
    }
}

public function getCustomers(){
    //The query method returns a mysqli_result object
    $result = $this->mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM customers');
    $customers = Array();

    if($result->num_rows >= 1){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $customer = new Customer($row['customerName'], $row['phoneNumber'], $row['emailAddress']);
            $customers[] = $customer;
        }
        $result->free();
        return $customers;
    }
    $result->free();
    return false;
}

/*
 * This is an example of how to use a prepared statement
 * with a select query.
 */
public function getCustomer($customerName){
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerName = ?';
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $customerName);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if($result->num_rows == 1){
        $temp = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $customer = new Customer($temp['customerName'], $temp['phoneNumber'], $temp['emailAddress']);
        $result->free();
        return $customer;
    }
    $result->free();
    return false;
}

public function addCustomer($customer){

    if(!$this->mysqli->connect_errno){

        $query = 'INSERT INTO customers VALUES (?,?,?)';

        $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);

        $stmt->bind_param('sss', 
                $customer->getCustomerName(), 
                $customer->getPhoneNumber(), 
                $customer->getEmailAddress());

        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->error){
            return $stmt->error;
        } else {
            return $customer->getCustomerName() . ' added successfully!';
        }
    } else {
        return 'Could not connect to Database.';
    }
}

}

?>
```

Let me know if you need any more code snippets.
Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Are you getting the error in `addCustomer`, `getCustomer` or both? Does get `getCustomers` work?

Comment: Here is the error message: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Week11Lab\customerDAO.php on line 59

Comment: I'm getting the error in addCustomer. I don't know if getCustomers works as I can't add an initial customer.

Comment: have a look at my answer and try the $mysqli->error property what does it say? Also change your insert statement so that it matches mine.

Comment: I get the following messages: 
Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\Week11Lab\customerDAO.php on line 57

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Week11Lab\customerDAO.php on line 57

Comment: Did you put `$this->mysqli->error` or just `$mysqli->error`

Comment: I used $mysqli->error. I updated it now and I'm getting these errors. Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\Week11Lab\customerDAO.php on line 57

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\Week11Lab\customerDAO.php on line 57

Comment: Just put `echo $this->mysqli->error` right after `$this->mysqli->prepare` and before `$stmt->bind_param`

Comment: I still get the same errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**mysqli::prepare**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) returns `false` if there was an error.

`false` is not an object, thus you get the error:

`call to method function on bind_param() on a non-object`.

You can get the error message by examining the `$mysqli->error` property.

```
public function addCustomer($customer) {
    if(!$this->mysqli->connect_errno) {

        $query = 'INSERT INTO customers (customerName,phoneNumber,emailAddress) 
                                 VALUES (?,?,?)';

        $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
        if (!$stmt) {
            $err = $this->mysqli->error;
            echo $err;
            // do something with $err
            return $err;
        }

        $stmt->bind_param('sss', 
            $customer->getCustomerName(), 
            $customer->getPhoneNumber(), 
            $customer->getEmailAddress());

        if(!$stmt->execute()){
            return $stmt->error;
        } else {
            return $customer->getCustomerName() . ' added successfully!';
        }
    } else {
        return 'Could not connect to Database.';
    }
}
```

The most typical reason why `prepare` fails is a malformed or invalid query, but without knowing the customer schema or constraints I can't be sure what your particular problem is.

Comment: @macattack Please see my updated answer, it focuses on the `addCustomer` method. You should be able to copy and paste it directly into your `customerDAO` class

Comment: Thanks that's helping with the debugging. Still not there though!

Comment: I have this error now which is at bind_param: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Customer::getCustomerName() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Week11Lab\customerDAO.php on line 92

Comment: @macattack Your customer class does not have a method called `getCustomerName`. In either case your DB issue looks to be solved. Please consider up voting and accepting my answer.